# JQuery - 15 Puzzle Game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, puzzle

Got a few questions (if you notice comments, yes I am reusing an old question because apparently my previous questions weren't "good enough" [blah]). Using JQuery to make a 15 Puzzle game for class and I have the code, there are still a few things that just don't seem to wanna work.

1. When the mouse hovers over the element, it should change the property by applying the movablepiece style. Well all I get is a black border.
2. Professor made a big deal last week about people copying and pasting code because he noticed they had code that wasn't covered in class and too advanced. Never said who so I assume he already talked to them, but I have previous experience with JScript and JQuery so I do things a big different because works more efficiently. Plus he knows I do, so this is an odd question in, do you for see a problem with that with my code? I don't. I do look at other code to see what they did, but don't copy paste, rather type and apply (much more ethical).

My code will be posted below.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <!--
  Homework 6: Fifteen Puzzle
  You should not modify fifteen.html.  Your JS code should work with an
  unmodified version of this file.
  -->
  <head>
    <title>Fifteen Puzzle</title>
        <link href="fifteen.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1.0/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- I had to add the line above for some reason. I couldn't get it to work for a very very long time and someone pointed me to
        this line of code above and it fixed all of my issues. -->
        <script src="fifteen.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Fifteen Puzzle</h1>

    <p>
      The goal of the fifteen puzzle is to un-jumble its fifteen squares
      by repeatedly making moves that slide squares into the empty space.
      How quickly can you solve it?
    </p>

    <div id="puzzlearea">
      <!-- the following are the actual fifteen puzzle pieces -->
      <div>1</div>  <div>2</div>  <div>3</div>  <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>  <div>6</div>  <div>7</div>  <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>  <div>10</div> <div>11</div> <div>12</div>
      <div>13</div> <div>14</div> <div>15</div>
    </div>

    <p id="controls">
      <button id="shufflebutton">Shuffle</button>
    </p>

    <p>
      American puzzle author and mathematician Sam Loyd is often falsely
      credited with creating the puzzle; indeed, Loyd claimed from 1891
      until his death in 1911 that he invented it.
      The puzzle was actually created around 1874 by Noyes Palmer Chapman,
      a postmaster in Canastota, New York.
    </p>

    <div id="w3c">
      <a href="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/validate.php"> 
        <img src="w3c-html.png" alt="Validate HTML5" width="88" height="31"/></a>
      <a href="https://webster.cs.washington.edu/validate-css.php"> 
        <img src="w3c-css.png" alt="Validate CSS" width="88" height="31"/></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

#controls {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin: 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Area where the puzzle piece are */
#puzzlearea {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 32pt;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* Applied to the puzzle pieces*/
.puzzlepiece {
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 2px solid black;
    cursor: default;
    height: 96px;
    line-height: 96px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 96px;
}

/* Applied to pieces that can move when mouse hovers */
.movablepiece:hover {
    border:2px solid red;
    color: red;
}
```

JQuery

```
var puzzle = [];
var bpiece = [];


window.onload = function() {
    puzzle =  $$("#puzzlearea div");
    var row = 0, right = 0, top = 0;

  for (var i=0;i<puzzle.length;i++){
        puzzle[i].addClassName("puzzlepiece");
        puzzle[i].style.float = "left";
       puzzle[i].style.backgroundSize = "400px 400px";

       bpiece[i] = [];
       bpiece[i][0] = right;
       bpiece[i][1] = top;

       puzzle[i].style.backgroundPosition = "-"+bpiece[i][0]+"px -"+bpiece[i][1]+"px";
       row ++;
       if (row === 4){top += 100; right = 0; row = 0; } else {right +=100;}
    }

  var freemove = document.createElement("div");
   $("puzzlearea").appendChild(freemove); //add a div that acts as the free move 
   blankP(freemove);


   puzzle = $$("#puzzlearea div"); // "reassign" the array puzzle with the new div added
   $("shufflebutton").observe('click', shufflePuzzle);
   movepiece();
};

// the function blankP is used to create the blank background for the space that represents the available move
var blankP = function(bSpace){
  bSpace.removeClassName("movablepiece");
  bSpace.addClassName("puzzlepiece");
  bSpace.style.float = "left";
  bSpace.style.backgroundImage = "none";
  bSpace.style.border = "2px solid white";
};

//the background_Position function is used to place the correct background piece to the number on the puzzlepiece.
var background_Position = function(piece , item){
  piece.style.backgroundPosition = "-"+bpiece[item-1][0]+"px -"+bpiece[item-1][1]+"px";
};

// the regularP function is used to apply the background to a numbered piece. 
var regularP = function(p){
      p.addClassName("puzzlepiece");
      p.style.border = "2px solid black";
      p.style.backgroundImage = "url(background.jpg)";
      p.style.backgroundSize = "400px 400px";
};

//the shuffluePuzzle function is used to shullfe each puzzle on the page.
function shufflePuzzle(){
    var numArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
    for (var i=puzzle.length; i>0; i){
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        var x = numArray[--i];
        var test = numArray[j];
        if(test == "0") { 
            puzzle[i].addClassName("puzzlepiece");
            blankP(puzzle[i]);
            puzzle[i].innerHTML = "";
                    }
        else{
                puzzle[i].innerHTML = numArray[j];
                regularP(puzzle[i]);
                background_Position(puzzle[i], test);
          }
            numArray[j] = x;
    }
    mopiece();
   }

//this function places the class movablepiece
var movePA = function(piece){
  puzzle[piece].addClassName("movablepiece");
};


//the movepiece function is used to actually move the piece that is clicked on into the space.
var movepiece = function(){
    var move = this.innerHTML;
    var yon = this.hasClassName('movablepiece');
    var blank = 0;
    if (yon){
        for (var i=0;i<puzzle.length;i++){
            blank = puzzle[i].innerHTML;
            if (puzzle[i].innerHTML == ""){
                puzzle[i].innerHTML = move;
                this.innerHTML = blank;

                regularP(puzzle[i]);
                blankP(this);

                 mopiece();
                 background_Position(puzzle[i], move);
      }    
     } 
   }
         };


//the function mopiece is used to calculate which pieces are beside the space and are able to move, thus applying the 'movablepiece' class
var mopiece = function(){
    for (var i=0;i<puzzle.length;i++){
        puzzle[i].removeClassName("movablepiece");  }
          for (var i=0; i<puzzle.length; i++){
            if (puzzle[i].innerHTML == ""){         
                  puzzle[i].removeClassName("movablepiece");

                switch(i){
                    case 0:
                        movePA(i+1);
                        movePA(i+4);
                                break;
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                        movePA(i-1);
                        movePA(i+1);
                            movePA(i+4);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        movePA(i-1);
                        movePA(i+4);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        movePA(i-4);
                        movePA(i+4);
                        movePA(i+1);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    case 9:
                    case 10:
                        movePA(i-4);
                        movePA(i+4);
                        movePA(i+1);
                        movePA(i-1);
                                break;
                    case 7: 
                    case 11:
                        movePA(i-4);
                        movePA(i+4);
                        movePA(i-1);
                                break;
                    case 8:
                        movePA(i-4);
                        movePA(i+1);
                        movePA(i+4);
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        movePA(i-4);
                        movePA(i+1);
                        break;
                    case 13: 
                    case 14:
                        movePA(i-4);
                        movePA(i-1);
                        movePA(i+1);
                        break;
                    case 15:
                        movePA(i-4);
                        movePA(i-1);
                        break;
                    }           
        }
                puzzle[i].observe('click', movepiece); }  
    }   ;
```

By the way, if you edit for my grammar or spelling on the post, please make sure you are helping me with the solution too. It frustrates to no end, sorry if you see that as helpful, but I don't because I want help with code. Already did all the grammar and spelling tests in the past and there is a reason I am a coder haha.

Comment: print your stack trace as well when you catch exception there . Because you are just not catching FNF exception, you are catching all possible Exceptions.

Comment: you'll get more help if you can reduce your code to a small working example of the problem.  sometimes that activity itself will clue you into the problem!

Comment: I have new errors now, please check the Edit section

Comment: For better help sooner please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and follow Jimmy's and Martin Serrano's suggestions

Comment: the comments above apply to previous question